# "recent future" is correct to use it?

Tags: adverbs, phrase-usage

In my communication in a translation community with one of the masters there, she used "recent future" instead of the known phrase, "near future".

From Information Retrieval perspective, we have about 680,000 entries according to Google, but my question is in which context do you prefer to use this phrase? Please provide some authenticated reference, because I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please provide some reasonable evidence of your own research. How do various dictionaries say that 'recent' may be used?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth this is what I am asking for. Don't get me wrong, I didn't exemplify google search results as a proof of correctness.

Comment: But ELU expects questions to be accompanied by reasonable research. KarlG has done this, but that was your responsibility.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you didn't read my question completely. In my last sentence, I pointed out my unsuccessful research to find a strict answer to its either correctness or incorrectness. My question's title is simply about the phrase validity and I didn't defend its correctness but you're trying to imply it's not questionable because that's a wrong phrase. I searched ELU too but nothing found and that made me to ask this question.

Comment: 'Recent future' is a very rare string, far from being a collocation/idiom. It is thus necessary to look up the words separately. You should have done this and posted your results. KarlG managed to do this without any problems. ELU is aimed at linguists and has required standards.

Answer (score 1):

It is not standard English, though it is not grammatically wrong

- your 680,000 entries on Google seem to me to be [closer to a rather smaller 231](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="recent+future"&start=229)
- some usage is coincidental juxtaposition such as references to a recent *Future of Work* conference
- some is jarring writing designed to provoke thought, such as Ellen Langer's 1989 *Mindfulness* saying "the present is an impending past and a recent future"
- some might be a time around now but which is not actually true, such as the New York Times review describing John Le Carré's *A Small Town in Germany* as being set in the recent future
- some is related to the music albums "A Recent Future" by James Keelaghan or "The Recent Future" by Adventure, again designed more to stand out rather than have a precise meaning
- some usage seems to be by writers with English as a second language

Comment: 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously, and the voters were recently voted.' is not grammatically wrong. But this doesn't make it acceptable. I'd say that OP's example involves a mistake rather than a string intended to jar.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I do not disagree with you

Answer (score 1):

Not only is the expression *recent future* highly non-idiomatic, but there is no commonly accepted [dictionary definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/recent?s=t) of *recent* which would allow its application to the future:

> 1. of late occurrence, appearance, or origin; lately happening, done, made, etc.:
>      recent events; a recent trip.
> 2. not long past:
>      in recent years.
> 3. of or belonging to a time not long past.

All these meanings point to a past, but proximate time. Proximate time in the future is the *near future*. A coinage such as *recent future*, though it would seem to mirror *recent past* perfectly, is in fact an *[oxymoron](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/oxymoron?s=t)*, a figure of speech composed of contradictory elements.

That doesn't mean, however, that no one has tried to find meaning in the tension between the two words. One [literary critic](https://www.depauw.edu/sfs/backissues/1/parrinder1art.htm) discusses certain dystopian science fiction novels, such as *Nineteen Eighty-Four* or *Player Piano*, as taking place in a "recent future" mostly as familiar as the recent past, but with a few crucial changes that alter a projected history. I would add that the British television series *Black Mirror*, with its critical view of recent technology gone terribly wrong, is an excellent example of such a genre.

What *near future* will never be, however, is a mundane time expression pointing to next week's dental appointment or when someone plans to do the shopping.

Comment: I prefer the definition of 'oxymoron' involving paradox rather than 'contradiction in terms'. 'Recent future' is probably classed alongside 'the month of Liverpool' rather than 'liquid gas'.

Comment: I just grabbed what dictionary.com had on offer. If _recent_ can only be past and I use it attributively with its logical opposite, then I've got cold fire or fiery ice.

Comment: ODO uses 'apparently contradictory', but the term is ill-defined.